# How to comment in Vim?

Tags: neovim, lunarvim

In VSCode I can comment my code with <kbd>Ctrl k</kbd><kbd>Ctrl c</kbd> and uncomment with <kbd>Ctrl k</kbd><kbd>Ctrl u</kbd>

Is there any way to do this using LunarVim or Neovim?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because "commenting out" is context-dependent, the behavior is left to plugins rather than the core Vim editor.

Many plugins reuse the sequence <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to comment.

- [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) (authored by the prolific [@tpope](https://github.com/tpope))
- [comment.nvim](https://github.com/numToStr/Comment.nvim) (included in LunarVim)
- [nerdcommenter](https://github.com/preservim/nerdcommenter) (uses `<Leader>cc`)
- [tcomment_vim](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim) (need and deserve love)
- [vim-tag-comment](https://github.com/mvolkmann/vim-tag-comment) (old but works very well for commenting tags)

Comment: Man, why does [tcomment](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim) never get any love?

Comment: Maybe converting the readme into markdown will make it more appealing?

Answer (score 2):

The standard and advised approach is to use a plugin, like Vivian wrote.

If you feel like not using a plugin, you can do it in a few lines of code using autocmd like the snippet below. Select several lines in visual mode with `V` and press Ctrl-Slash or Shift-Ctrl-Slash to comment/uncomment.

The idea is simple. The buffer-local variable `b:comment_symbol` is defined corresponding to the file type (you can see with `echo &ft`). If you substitute `b:comment_symbol` for start-of-line,  you comment a line. If you substitute nothing for `b:comment_symbol` at start-of-line, you uncomment a line.

(This is standard vim, sorry idk if it works in neovim or lunarvim)

```
augroup visual_commenting
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType c,cpp,java,rust  let b:comment_symbol = '//'
    autocmd FileType vim              let b:comment_symbol = '"'
    autocmd FileType sh,vim,python    let b:comment_symbol = '#'
    autocmd FileType tex              let b:comment_symbol = '%'
    autocmd BufEnter * silent! vnoremap <silent> <C-_> :<C-u>keepp '<,'>s@^@\=b:comment_symbol<CR>
    autocmd BufEnter * silent! exec 'vnoremap <silent> <C-?> :<C-u>keepp ''<,''>s@^' . b:comment_symbol . '@<CR>'
augroup END
```

Comment: If there is no linewise comment e.g. like in coq, just substitute both start-of-line and end-of-line.